# How to put spaces between buttons using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I have these three buttons:
I trying to put some spaces between these 3 buttons using bootstrap only, but I always fail.
So, how can I put some spaces and not ruin the responsive design?
I need the same space size between the buttons (small/medium/large spaces).

```
<h4>Welcome to Server Manager 4.0</h4>
<p>Manage your Servers and Users.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 justify-content-around" style="background-color:lightgray;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary " (click)="onLoadServers(1)">Load Servers 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onLogin()">Login</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to use this class:

```
justify-content-around
```

In addition, I also tried to put each button in each column and play with the 'col-sm-3' up to 12 , but it was worse!

What I always see is (not what I need):

[image]

Comment: I working according to an old tutorial, so the version is 3.4.1

Comment: I saw your solution,  it works in your IDE. --> But I using VSCode (angular project) and it doesn`t work there....

Answer (score 1):

Use margin helper class:

css:

```
.mx {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightgray;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mx " (click)="onLoadServers(1)">Load Servers 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success mx" (click)="onLogin()">Login</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger mx" (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried this too! --> NOT WORKING

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/Lhgd1fpk/ working fine

Comment: It is working if I change to col-lg-3, but still I it gives me large spaces, I want to control these spaces according to my requierments.

Comment: Let`s say, I will be satisfied with small spaces only

Comment: I think bootstrap 3 doesn't have margin class helpers. So you create your own class. I updated my answer.

Comment: Let me know if solve your problem.